# What use for nesting elements in a table

Tags: html

I have a html page which looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                    <div>
                        <tr>...</tr>
                        <tr>...</tr>
                   </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Why the tr inside the div arent' showed? and in the page element i see the div outside the table? I thought I could put a div in a table if it was inside a tr..

Comment: this is an invalid HTML. You can not add div to tbody.

Comment: What you need to do with this div ?

Comment: And you also use wrong the `head` tag. learn HTML basics please. http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: @lolka_bolka: and that would be the answer to the question.

Comment: Use `colspan`/`rowspan` for asymmetric tables, use `tbody`/`colgroup` for grouping

Answer (score 0):

> Why the tr inside the div arent' showed?

It doesn't fit in HTML's model of a table.

Look at thead / tfoot / tbody instead.

> and in the page element i see the div outside the table?

The browser is trying to recover from your error

> I thought I could put a div in a table if it was inside a tr..

You thought wrong. You can only put a div in a table if it is inside a td or a th.

Comment: ... or inside a caption if it's HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Add a DTD -->
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Meta tags, styles, javascripts comes here -->
        <title>This is the title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <!-- Close head before body -->
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- Use td(s) in tr -->
                        <div></div> <!-- use div inside the td -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does this answer have so many downvotes? I actually find it very helpful for the OP.

Comment: @StevenPalinkas Sometimes I am wondering why peoples downvote a working code with explanations.